# Kahler manifold computation

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds, complex-manifolds

In the following derivation, done on a Kahler manifold, where $\nabla$ is the complexification of the Riemannian connection (i.e., since we are on a Kahler manifold, this is the same thing as the Chern connection on holomorphic forms extended to the conjugate bundle in the natural way):

[image]

Where $\nabla_{i} \phi_{I_{p} \overline{J_{q}}} $ means $(\nabla_{i} \phi)_{I_{p} \overline{J_{q}}}$, i.e. we are taking a component of $\nabla_{i} \phi$, rather than taking the covariant derivative of a smooth function. I do not immediately see why it is clear that the symmetry of Christoffel symbols is enough to ensure the equality in the final line. It would be great if anyone could expand on why this is immediate.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The Christoffel symbols $\Gamma^a_{bc}$ are symmetric in the two indices $b,c$, so $\Gamma^a_{bc}\mathrm{d}z^b\wedge\mathrm{d}z^c=0$ as the wedge product of the forms is anti-symmetric. You are contracting symmetric indices with anti-symmetric ones.
I don't know if there is anything beyond this, let me know what you think.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I think I can understand why it is zero when we are taking a wedge product of two one forms as in what you wrote, but when we are swapping $dz^i$ and $dz^{i_s}$ wouldn't the factor be some power of $-1$ depending on $s$?

Comment: Not really, the wedge product $\zeta^1\wedge\ldots\wedge\zeta^k$ is anti-symmetric in all indices. Consider this: if we want to exchange $\zeta^1$ with $\zeta^s$ we can first move $\zeta^s$ next to $\zeta^1$, on the right. This gives you a factor of $(-1)^{s-2}$. Then we exchange $\zeta^1$ and $\zeta^s$, which gives another $-1$. Then you move the $\zeta^1$ that is now in second place after $\zeta^{s-1}$, which gives you another $(-1)^{s-2}$. All in all, you end up with sign $(-1)^{2(s-2)+1}=-1$.

Comment: By the way, it seems to me that the "proof" above does not really work. The definition of $\nabla^{1,0}\phi$ is $\nabla_{a}\phi_{I\bar{J}}\mathrm{d}z^a\otimes\mathrm{d}z^I\wedge\mathrm{d}\bar{z}^J$. The Proposition does hold, however, you just need to read the "proof" backwards.

Comment: @JohnnyLemmon Oh doh! Of course the wedge product is antisymmetric in all indices! Thanks for spelling that out for me lol. Replying to your latest comment, I agree, I don't think $D' = \nabla^{(1,0)}$ should have been used. The proof should have started with the RHS of the Proposition equality, since that is exactly the expression on the RHS of $D' = $ in the first line after the start of the Proof, am I interpreting your second remark correctly? Thanks again for the replies! I'd be happy to accept an answer if you want to type one out.

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I had in mind. I attempted to spell some details out in the answer below. I tried to formulate the problem in a slightly more general context, your Proposition in the Kähler case should follow readily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is a more coherent explanation of the comments I wrote to the question. First, I think it might be important to note that a version of this Proposition holds in less restrictive situations than Kähler manifolds.

**Claim.** Let $D$ be a torsion-free connection on $TM$. We can extend $D$ to a connection on $\Lambda^{k}T^*M$, using the duality between $TM$ and $T^*M$. Then, if $\phi$ is a $k$-form on $M$, the differential $\mathrm{d}\phi$ can be written as
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{d}\phi=D_a\phi_{b_1\dots b_n}\mathrm{d}x^a\wedge\mathrm{d}x^{b_1}\wedge\ldots\wedge\mathrm{d}x^{b_k}.
\end{equation}

Notice that this is *not* saying that $\mathrm{d}\phi=D\phi$, as the proof in the original question seems to imply. Instead, this claim tells us that the completely anti-symmetric part of $D\phi$ is just $\mathrm{d}\phi$, as a consequence of $D$ being torsion-free.

So, how do we prove this? As mentioned in the comments above, the crucial point is that the wedge product $\mathrm{d}x^a\wedge\mathrm{d}x^{b_1}\wedge\ldots\wedge\mathrm{d}x^{b_k}$ is completely anti-symmetric, i.e. anti-symmetric in all indices, while the Christoffel symbols $\Gamma^a_{bc}$ of $D$ are symmetric in $b,c$, as $D$ is torsion-free. So, we can compute
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\mathrm{d}\phi=&\partial_a\phi_{b_1\dots b_n}\mathrm{d}x^a\wedge\mathrm{d}x^{b_1}\wedge\ldots\wedge\mathrm{d}x^{b_k}=\\
=&D_a\phi_{b_1\dots b_n}\mathrm{d}x^a\wedge\mathrm{d}x^{b_1}\wedge\ldots\wedge\mathrm{d}x^{b_k}+\\
&+\sum_j\Gamma^{c}_{a b_j}\phi_{b_1\dots b_{j-1}c\,b_{j+1}\dots b_n}\mathrm{d}x^a\wedge\mathrm{d}x^{b_1}\wedge\ldots\wedge\mathrm{d}x^{b_k}=\\
=&D_a\phi_{b_1\dots b_n}\mathrm{d}x^a\wedge\mathrm{d}x^{b_1}\wedge\ldots\wedge\mathrm{d}x^{b_k}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
as $\Gamma^c_{ab_j}\mathrm{d}x^a\wedge\mathrm{d}x^{b_1}\wedge\ldots\wedge\mathrm{d}x^{b_k}=0$, since we are contracting a symmetric object with an anti-symmetric one.